# ( Did with verb ) or ( had with verb+ed )

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

I'm confused with rules .

**My question** : what is the different between this examples :

- **Did you** finish your homework before you went to the cinema ?
- **Had you** finished your homework before you went to the cinema ?
- The waiter served something that **we didn't order** .
  The waiter served something that **we had not ordered** .

Are the sentences correct? If it is not, what is the mistake?

Thank you .
Nouf .

Comment: _Did you finish_ is a past tense construction with _do_-support. _Have you finished_ is a present tense perfect construction. Thus, this question is a duplicate of every question here asking about the "simple" past versus the present perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct and sound natural. It is confusing! I think most people use "did" more than "had".